# Finding total count for word form when many possible POS tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, linguistics

I feel like I have a dumb question, but here goes anyway.. 
I'm trying to go from data that looks something like this:

```
a word form     lemma    POS                count of occurrance
same word form  lemma    Not the same POS   another count
same word form  lemma    Yet another POS    another count
```

to a result that looks like this:

```
the word form    total count    all possible POS and their individual counts
```

So for example I could have:

```
ring     total count = 100        noun = 40, verb = 60
```

I have my data in a CSV file. I want to do something like this:

```
for row in all_rows:
    if row[0] is the same as row[0] in the next row, add the values from row[3] together to get the total count
```

buuut I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Help?

Comment: Didn't you mean `if column[0] is the same as column[0] in next row...` ?

Comment: Hmm. My idea is to go row by row, because I have multiple words in my data and I want to keep the total count of the word forms that look the same but have different POS tags (to ring a bell, to wear a ring). So if the 0th element of the row number 1 (which is the word form) is the same as the 0th element of row number 2, add together the values that come from the 3rd element of those rows to get the total count for the word form.

Comment: ..which yeah, technically is the column.

Comment: You were right, actually row[0] is a column, so I have no idea why I asked that question, but initially I got confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the simplest way to achieve what you need would be:

```
# Mocked CSV data
data = [
 ['a', 'lemma', 'pos', 1],
 ['a', 'lemma', 'pos1', 2],
 ['a', 'lemma', 'pos2', 3],
 ['b', 'lemma', 'pos', 5],
]

result = {}

for row in data:
  key = row[0]
  count = row[3]
  if key in result:
    result[key] += count
  else:
    result[key] = count

print(result)
```

Result:

```
{
  'a': 6,
  'b': 5
}
```